# Why Sending multi-part form data using SSL & POCO returns status 411?

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

I have written an interface to use the JIRA Service Desk API. One of the REST API calls I have implemented does a HTTP POST of multipart/form-data. This works fine when i use HTTP, however when I use HTTPS i get a `411 Length Required` response.

The REST API call command works fine over HTTPS when I use curl or postman.

Is there something I am missing when HTTPS is used?

my form post code is as follows:

```
// generic form send
RESTClient::Error RESTClient::HTTPFormSend(
    const std::string & method,
    const std::string & command,
    const Params & headerParams,
    Poco::Net::HTMLForm & form,
    HTTPRequestSetup requestFunc
)
{
    Error ret = Error::None;

    try
    {
        Poco::Net::HTTPRequest request;

        Poco::SharedPtr<Poco::Net::HTTPClientSession> pSession(PrepareSession(method, command, headerParams, request));

        Poco::Net::HTTPResponse httpResponse;

        // authenticate
        m_credentials.authenticate(request);

        // custom request setup    
        if (requestFunc)
            requestFunc(request);

        if (!DoFormRequest(pSession, request, httpResponse, form))
        {
            m_credentials.authenticate(request);

            if (!DoFormRequest(pSession, request, httpResponse, form))
            {
                m_logger.error("Invalid username or password");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (const Poco::Exception &ex)
    {
        m_logger.error(ex.displayText());
        ret = Error::Internal;
    }

    return ret;
}

// send form
bool RESTClient::DoFormRequest(
    Poco::Net::HTTPClientSession *pSession,
    Poco::Net::HTTPRequest & request,
    Poco::Net::HTTPResponse & response,
    Poco::Net::HTMLForm &form
)
{
    Poco::LogStream logStream(m_logger);

    form.prepareSubmit(request);

    pSession->setTimeout(Poco::Timespan(20, 0));

    form.write(pSession->sendRequest(request));

    return ProcessResponse(pSession, response);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Poco::Net::HTMLForm::prepareSubmit()` will normally use Chunked Transfer-Encoding when submitting multipart forms, so no `Content-Length` header will be set. As a workaround, you could try to set the HTTP Version of the request to 1.0 before calling `prepareSubmit()`. This will force `prepareSubmit()` to calculate the length and set the `Content-Length` header, instead of using Chunked Transfer Encoding. After calling `prepareSubmit()`, you can reset the HTTP version to 1.1.

```
request.setVersion(Poco::Net::HTTPMessage::HTTP_1_0);
form.prepareSubmit(request);
request.setVersion(Poco::Net::HTTPMessage::HTTP_1_1);
```

Comment: Thanks, but without this work around why does it work when i use HTTPClientSesswion and not HTTPSClientSession?

Comment: Probably a restriction of the JIRA Service Desk API HTTPS server.